# Java execution shutdown does not terminate all threads?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I have following sample created to mimic the situation i am encountering related to ExecutionService shutdown process. It seems that it terminates only one thread out of 3 something... and i get error messages on tomcat server.

```
public class Test {
static final ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

static Runnable getTask(final String name) {

    return new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.setName("Thread-" + name);
            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(name + " running...[" + this.getName() + "]");
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("InterruptedException..." + this.getName());
throw new Exception(e);
                }
            }

        }
    };
}

public static void main(String... strings) {
    threadExecutor.submit(getTask("Task-1"));
    threadExecutor.submit(getTask("Task-2"));
    threadExecutor.submit(getTask("Task-3"));
    //--
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) threadExecutor;
            System.out.println("Active Threads=====>" + tpe.getActiveCount());
            tpe.shutdown();
            try {
                if (!threadExecutor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    System.out.println("Executor did not terminate in the specified time.");
                    List<Runnable> droppedTasks = tpe.shutdownNow();
                    System.out.println("Shutdown thread pool forecibly. " + droppedTasks.size() + " tasks will not be executed.");
                }
                System.out.println("Active Threads=====>" + tpe.getActiveCount());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutdown()` initiates the shutdown process within the thread pool but allows current running tasks to finish. In your example the task does not finish because of `while(true)`.

`shutdownNow()` initiates the shutdown and also interrupts the currently running threads. But again your task is handling that interrupted exception and running the `while(true)` loop.

I think you can simply share a common boolean between your tasks and caller code from where you are calling the `threadPoolExecuror.shutdown()`. Use that boolean in task instead of `while(true)`.